# [UIBarButtonItem _isAncestorOfFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, core-data, uikit, uibarbuttonitem, magicalrecord

This code works perfectly in one app and crashes in another with message:

```
[UIBarButtonItem _isAncestorOfFirstResponder]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

If I comment the magical record code I can see that method runs OK.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNote:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
}


- (IBAction)addNote:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    Note *note = [Note MR_createInContext:localContext];
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    note.date = now;
    note.person = _person;
    [localContext MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveSynchronously completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

        UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary[@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:NSBundle.mainBundle];
        NoteViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NoteViewController"];
        vc.note = note;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }];
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UILabel *noResultsLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.tableView.bounds.size.width)];
    noResultsLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.557 alpha:1.000];
    noResultsLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35];
    noResultsLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    noResultsLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"No notes", nil);
    self.tableView.nxEV_emptyView = noResultsLabel;

    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Fetched results controller
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"person == %@", _person];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [Note MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"source" withPredicate:predicate sortedBy:@"source,date" ascending:YES delegate:self];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
{
    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)selectCreatedRowatIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
}
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:(NoteCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
    if (sectionInfo.name.intValue == 0) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"Not Secret", @"Notes");
    }else return NSLocalizedString(@"Secret", @"Notes");
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Note Cell";

    NoteCell *cell = (NoteCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
- (void)configureCell:(NoteCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Note *note = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.dateLabel.text = [[CZDateFormatterCache mainQueueCache] localizedStringFromDate:note.date dateStyle:kCFDateFormatterLongStyle timeStyle:kCFDateFormatterShortStyle];

    if (note.note.length > 0) {
        cell.noteLabel.text = note.note;
    } else {
        cell.noteLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"New Note", nil);
    }

    cell.rateView.rate = [note.trustworthy intValue];
    NSLog(@"note.trustworthy intValue %i", [note.trustworthy intValue]);

    cell.rateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [MagicalRecord saveUsingCurrentThreadContextWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] MR_deleteInContext:localContext];
        } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
            //
        }];
    }
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return NO;
}

#pragma mark - Segue
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
                 sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Note Segue"]) {
        NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        Note *note = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NoteViewController *anvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        anvc.note = note;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think there is a problem when you push your new controller. Are you using ARC? Could you post some other details?

Comment: @flexaddicted Yes, the problem raises up mostly when I push controller, however I found that rare it crashes even without it. And yes, I use ARC. I'll update my post.

Comment: @flexaddicted I posted all the methods I have in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was in the second view controller.
I found it occasionally.

I used `UIBarButtonItem` with custom view as a navigation bar `titleView`.